# How to add multiple shadow layers of boxShadow with Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I try to build a boxShadow generator, where the user can add multiple layers of boxShadow. Anything like the example below:

```
box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
```

What I have so far:

A constructor function, which creates my shadows.

```
function Shadow(paramId) {
    this.shadowId = paramId;
    this.horizontalValue = 'horizontalRange' + paramId;
    this.verticalValue = 'verticalRange' + paramId;
    this.blurValue = 'blurRange' + paramId;
    this.spreadValue = 'spreadRange' + paramId;
    this.colorValue = 'colorInput' + paramId;
}
```

...and a function, which gets the value of the sliders:

```
function getRangeValue () {
    const shadowBox = document.getElementById('shadowBox');
    let shadowId = this.id.slice(this.id.length - 1, this.id.length) - 1; // my Id's are like xOffset1
    let xValue = document.getElementById(shadowObjContainer[shadowId].horizontalValue).value;
    let yValue = document.getElementById(shadowObjContainer[shadowId].verticalValue).value;
    let blurValue = document.getElementById(shadowObjContainer[shadowId].blurValue).value;
    let spreadValue = document.getElementById(shadowObjContainer[shadowId].spreadValue).value;
    let colorValue = document.getElementById(shadowObjContainer[shadowId].colorValue).value;
    
    shadowParam = `${xValue}px ${yValue}px ${blurValue}px ${spreadValue}px ${colorValue}`;
   
    shadowBox.style.boxShadow = shadowParam;
}
```

It does work, that my sliders do what they are supposed to do. But I don't know, how to create another shadow parameter (", " + shadowParam).

Hopefully someone can help me.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example to work on was helpful. I hypothesized your environment and this is my commented idea.

```js
// The class with all controls for each shadows
let Control = class {
  constructor(paramId) {
    this.shadowId = paramId;
    this.horizontalValue = 'horizontalRange' + paramId;
    this.verticalValue = 'verticalRange' + paramId;
    this.blurValue = 'blurRange' + paramId;
    this.spreadValue = 'spreadRange' + paramId;
    this.colorValue = 'colorInput' + paramId;
  }
}

// Generates the shadow for each initialized Control class 
function getRangeValue() {
  const shadowBox = document.getElementById('shadowBox');
  let shadowParam = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < Controls.length; i++) {
    let shadowId = Controls[i].shadowId;
    let xValue = document.getElementById(Controls[i].horizontalValue).value;
    let yValue = document.getElementById(Controls[i].verticalValue).value;
    let blurValue = document.getElementById(Controls[i].blurValue).value;
    let spreadValue = document.getElementById(Controls[i].spreadValue).value;
    let colorValue = document.getElementById(Controls[i].colorValue).value;

    shadowParam = (shadowParam == '' ? '' : shadowParam + ', ') + `${xValue}px ${yValue}px ${blurValue}px ${spreadValue}px ${colorValue}`;
  }
  shadowBox.style.boxShadow = shadowParam;
}

// Initialization of the Control classes based on the "group" of controls named "ShadowControls"
let ShadowControlsEl = document.getElementsByClassName("ShadowControls");
let Controls = Array();
for (let i = 0; i < ShadowControlsEl.length; i++) {
  Controls.push(new Control(i + 1));
}

// Generate the first Shadows
getRangeValue();

// Initialize listeners for values change
let AllControls = document.getElementsByClassName('listener');
for (let i = 0; i < AllControls.length; i++) {
  AllControls[i].addEventListener('change', getRangeValue);
}
```

```css
#shadowBox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ShadowControls">
  <input id="horizontalRange1"  class="listener" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="10">
  <input id="verticalRange1"    class="listener" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="10">
  <input id="blurRange1"        class="listener" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input id="spreadRange1"      class="listener" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input id="colorInput1"       class="listener" type="color" value="#FF0000">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="ShadowControls">
  <input id="horizontalRange2"  class="listener" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="-10">
  <input id="verticalRange2"    class="listener" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="-10">
  <input id="blurRange2"        class="listener" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input id="spreadRange2"      class="listener" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input id="colorInput2"       class="listener" type="color" value="#FFFF00">
</div>



<div id="shadowBox">
  Shadow here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it basically works, is just have to figure out how to implement your code snippet into my existing code. My main issue is this code snippet: shadowParam = (shadowParam == '' ? '' : shadowParam + ', ') + `${xValue}px ${yValue}px ${blurValue}px ${spreadValue}px ${colorValue}`; Can you explain it to me, please?

Comment: It is simply a shorthand for `if`.  Is the same of `if (shadowParam == '') { '' } else { shadowParam + ', ' }`. With this code I concatenate the old `shoadowParam` plus `, ` only if the `shadowParam` isn't blank (not on the first cycle).